# pure c support/util library

Tags: c

I am searching a library in C/pragma/.. for basic programming tasks. 
Something for handling and creating Lists and hasmaps and arrays and souch stuff.
So i dont have to reinvent the wheel again and again and write the same structures again and again.
But has to be **pure C library**.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why exactly does it need to be pure C? what about STL? (and what about the C++ tag?)

Comment: often c++ programmers got a good knowledge of c libs, too. thats why i added the c++ tag. thanks for vote.

Comment: This comment belongs on meta... but I wonder if SO shouldn't have 2 sets of tags for each questions: one set for what the question itself is about, and another for related topics/languages whose experts might be able to help answer the question. Then users following the c++ tag could pick if they just wanted to see "about c++" questions or both "about c++" and "answerable by c++ experts" questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to retag your question and remove the C++ tag, as your question is a little strange with the tag.

If you need something implemented in C, then look at [Glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/), which is part of GTK+, and it implements data structures like linked lists and trees.

Alternatively, the [Apache Portable Runtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Portable_Runtime) is a project from Apache which is also written in C, and is used in the Apache web server.

Comment: Contrary to OP's requirements, neither of these libraries is "pure C". They're both full of dependencies on either POSIX or one of a particular set of supported proprietary operating systems because they do a lot more than what can be done at the pure C library level.

Comment: @R - You're right, they're not pure C. I took the OP's question to mean 'libraries implemented with C and no C++', not 'libraries that were written with C and no outside influences like OS-level details'.

Answer (score 3):

In plain c projects I tend to use the [APR](http://apr.apache.org/).

Maybe it covers all the things you need. And it provides a nice abstraction of the OS too.

Answer (score 3):

[Glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.28/)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, you might take a look at the source code accompanying the book *[C Interfaces and Implentations](http://sites.google.com/site/cinterfacesimplementations/)*.